# Collecting results from a list of Futures in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to use futures to make concurrent api calls. Code:

```
private void init() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<ApiResponse> responses = fetchAllUsingFuture(ids, 3);
    log.info(responses.toString());
    Long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info(MessageFormat.format("Process duration: {0} in ms", finish-start));
}

private List<ApiResponse> fetchAllUsingFuture(List<String> ids, int threadCount) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
    List<List<String>> chunks = Utils.splitToChunks(ids, threadCount);
    List<Future<List<ApiResponse>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    chunks.forEach(chunk -> {
        futures.add(wrapFetchInFuture(chunk));
    });
    Future<List<ApiResponse>> resultFuture = executorService.submit(() -> {
        List<ApiResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();
        futures.forEach(future -> {
            try {
                responses.addAll(future.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return responses;
    });

    executorService.shutdown();
    return resultFuture.get();
}



private Future<List<ApiResponse>> wrapFetchInFuture(List<String> ids) {
    return new FutureTask<>(() -> {
        List<ApiResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();
        ids.forEach(id -> {
            responses.add(fetchData(id));
        });
        return responses;
    });
}

private ApiResponse fetchData(String id) {
    ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(id, ApiResponse.class);
    log.info(MessageFormat.format("Fetching from {0}", id));
    ApiResponse body = response.getBody();
    log.info(MessageFormat.format("Retrieved {0}", body));
    return body;
}
```

It doesn't execute, the app starts and then just pends. Futures don't get fulfilled. All advices are appreciated.
P.S. I'm aware this is much more easily done using CompletableFuture, I was just wondering how to do this with Futures

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html

Comment: From what I see, you do create the `FutureTask`s, but never start them. So... if the tasks are not started, they cannot terminate.

Comment: @Turing85 yeah, you're correct I edited the code. Same result though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original version of the question, you are creating a list of `FutureTasks` but never send them to the `ExecutorService` to run them. The tasks never complete, so `Future.get` blocks forever.

In the updated version of the question, you have put the code that does the waiting into the executor service as a task. The FutureTasks never run, so `FutureTask.get` will still block forever.

I would suggest you change the code in `fetchAllUsingFuture` to:

```
    List<Callable<List<ApiResponse>>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    chunks.forEach(chunk -> {
        tasks.add(wrapFetchInCallable(chunk));
    });
    List<Future<List<ApiResponse>>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
```

where `wrapFetchInCallable` creates a `Callable` instead of `FutureTask`:

```
private static Callable<List<ApiResponse>> wrapFetchInCallable(List<String> ids) {
    return () -> {
        List<ApiResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();
        ids.forEach(id -> {
            responses.add(fetchData(id));
        });
        return responses;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are creating a list of FutureTasks but never send them to the ExecutorService to run them.
I have implemented ExecutorService with Future Object as below, i hope it helps you:

Service layer:

```
public List<MovieDTO> searchMoviesParallel(String limit, String offset, String searchPhrase) throws Exception {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Future<List<MovieDTO>> digitoonResult = executor.submit(new DigitoonSearchTask(limit, offset, searchPhrase));
        List<MovieDTO> movieDTOList = digitoonResult.get();
        executor.shutdown();

        return movieDTOList;
    }
```

And my Search task(DigitoonSearchTask class) is as below:

```
public class DigitoonSearchTask implements Callable<List<MovieDTO>> {

    private String limit;
    private String offset;
    private String searchPhrase;

    private final static String digitoonSearchBaseUrl = "http://apitwo.xxx.com/partner/search/?q=";

    public DigitoonSearchTask(String limit, String offset, String searchPhrase) {
        this.limit = limit;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.searchPhrase = searchPhrase;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MovieDTO> call() throws Exception {
        List<MovieDTO> movieDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            String uri = digitoonSearchBaseUrl + URLEncoder.encode(searchPhrase, "utf-8") + "&limit=" + limit + "&offset=" + offset;
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("authorization", "xxxxxxxxxx");
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                movieDTOList = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(output, MovieDTO[].class));
            }
            br.close();
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            call();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return movieDTOList;
    }}
```

consider that now I have just one API and after getting others they can be added as another Search task in service layer by increasing the thread number.